# excel vba find start and end row in column for multiple variables

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

In excel, I have a helper column (col O) that has a formula in each cell, the formula lets me know when the data changes from 1 to 2 to 3 to 4 etc.  For this data set rows 2-7 are "1", 8-16 are "2", 16-22 are "3". Using some formulas on the sheet I plan on looping thru the ranges, i =1-3 in this example. lrow is the last row of data on the sheet (lrow = 22). `Range("P1")` is the max # in the helper column.

In the code below StartRow works just fine, the EndRow is what's not working. When i=1 `StartRow` should be 2, and `EndRow` should be 7, but it keeps returning 22 or sometimes 21. I'm not sure how to get `EndRow`= to 7, then 16, then 22. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

```
   For i = Range("o2").Value To Range("P1").Value


    '----------loop check for multiple BOMs

    Dim StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long
    With Sheets("BOM Load")

        StartRow = .Range("o1:O" & lrow).Find(what:=i, after:=.Range("o1")).Row
'   EndRow = .Range("o2:O" & lrow).Find(what:=i,after:=.Range("o2"),searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    EndRow = .Range("o1:O" & lrow).Find(what:=i, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long, StartRow as Long, EndRow as Long

With Sheets("BOM Load")
    For i = 1 To 3
        StartRow = .Range("O:O").Find(i, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
        EndRow = .Range("O:O").Find(i, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

I've:

- Added `LookIn:=xlValues` to tell VBA to **not** look in `xlFormulas`
- Added `LookAt:=xlWhole` to tell VBA to prevent matches that hold part of what we looking for > `10` when we look for `1`.
- Left out `After:=` since by default the `Find` is performed from the top left cell in specified range
- Changed `.Range("o1:O" & lrow)` to `.Range("O:O")` because we don't need it to look in a specified area of the column (unless you have data below the data you want to look through)

<sub>**Note:** You have also still used an implicit range reference in `For i = Range("o2").Value To Range("P1").Value` refering to the `ActiveSheet`. You might want to address that issue too.</sub>

Comment: Any luck with this @AlbertoBrown

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. your solution worked. i used the range values for the loop because the # of loops will change each time the users use the sheet. I thought limiting the range the code looked at would maybe speed up the search but just using `.Range("O:O")` was what fixed the issue